# Format Laravel collections

Tags: php, laravel, collections, laravel-5

I have a Laravel collection like the following which is obtained as a result of database query(Query builder, not Eloquent).

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [product_name] => Product 1 
                    [sub_product_name] => sub_prod_1
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [product_name] => Product 1
                    [sub_product_name] => sub_prod_2
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [product_name] => Product 1
                    [sub_product_name] => sub_prod_3
                )

            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [product_name] => Product 2
                    [sub_product_name] => sub_prod_21
                )

            [4] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [product_name] => Product 2
                    [sub_product_name] => sub_prod_22
                )

            [5] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [product_name] => Product 2
                    [sub_product_name] => sub_prod_23
                )

            [6] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [product_name] => Product 3
                    [sub_product_name] => sub_prod_31
                )
        )
)
```

Now I would like to transform the array like the following and to send it as an API response. Basically this is initialising counts for each of the product and then later, counts will be added to this.

```
Array
    (
        [Product 1 ] => stdClass Object
            (
                sub_prod_1 => 0,
                sub_prod_2 => 0,
                sub_prod_3 => 0
            ),
        [Product 2 ] => stdClass Object
            (
                sub_prod_21 => 0,
                sub_prod_22 => 0,
                sub_prod_23 => 0
            ),
        [Product 3 ] => stdClass Object
            (
                sub_prod_31 => 0,
            )
)
```

It is also fine if it has one more layer, I mean like [0][Product 1]

I have used groupBy like this

```
$productPoints = $productCollection->groupBy(function ($item) {
            return $item->product_name;
 });
```

but is not giving the desired result. How can I do it using Laravel collection methods ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is this. The parameter should be the name of the key not the value in your case.

`$productPoints = $productCollection->groupBy('product_name');`